# Is there a tool to speed up React src code compilation?

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5.7

I just started learning React and I was wondering if there is some tool or package that helps with the source code compilation.

What I do is always run `npm run dev` whenever I want to see the changes, is there something easier and faster, or that makes more sense?

PS: in my particular case I'm using ***React backed by Laravel 5.7*** but I don't think this can help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Look at create-react-app (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started). It is a good beginner's template and has the monitoring of the files for changes. From it you can learn how it is done.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out